# Expo TypeScript Tabs Snapshot Test App.tsx

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, expo

I initialized a default Expo project using Typescript and Tabs option.

Follow these directions (https://docs.expo.io/get-started/create-a-new-app/) and select the Typescript with Tabs option.

Then I tried to follow the directions for creating a unit test here: https://docs.expo.io/guides/testing-with-jest/?redirected

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this test to work:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import App from './App';

describe('<App />', () => {
  it('has 1 child', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
    expect(tree.children.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can my answer below help you? If no, please provide more details for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story but I will keep it short.

From the template you chose and guideline in repo, `jest`, `jest-expo` and `react-test-renderer` should be installed.

For typescript, you also need to install type definition as well.

```sh
yarn add --dev jest
yarn add --dev jest-expo
yarn add --dev react-test-renderer

// type definiton 
yarn add --dev @types/jest
yarn add --dev @types/react-test-renderer
```

To config the jest, let's stick with expo default where the configuration is placed in package.json

**package.json**

```json
...
"jest": {
    // using jest-expo instead of react-native to allow expo to mock the libraries/API for us implicitly
    "preset": "jest-expo", 

    // include ts, tsx, js, jsx to allow jest to recognise those file extension.
    // tsx must be placed higher than json. 
    // Otherwise, in the test file, when we do [import App from 'App.tsx'], 
    // jest will treat it as importing app.json instead of App.tsx
    "moduleFileExtensions": [ 
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json"
    ],

    // The default recommendation from jest.
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ]
},
...
```

As `jest-expo` mocks some of the libraries for us, including SafeAreaProvider, there is nothing to test actually. (You can create your own mock for it to test it but it is out of scope in this question.) To be able to count the children successfully. We add a View and Text for testing.

**App.tsx**

```js
export default function App() {
  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  if (!isLoadingComplete) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        {/* Add a dummy View and Text for testing */}
        <View>
          <Text></Text>
        </View>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
          <StatusBar />
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**Create `App.test.tsx`**

```js
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import App from './App';

// mock the useCachedResources, so the if block in App.tsx can render component instead of returning null.
jest.mock('./hooks/useCachedResources', () => jest.fn(() => true))

describe('<App />', () => {
  it('has 1 child', () => {
    // cast the returning result as renderer.ReactTestRendererJSON[] array
    // because it contains 2 sections - [ View, SafeAreaProvider ]
    const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON() as renderer.ReactTestRendererJSON[];

    // console log for you to see the result 
    console.log(tree)

    // View should have one child
    expect(tree[0].children?.length).toBe(1);

    // SafeAreaProvider has no children
    expect(tree[1].children).toBe(null);

    // matching snapshot
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

A demo repo is on [GitHub](https://github.com/michael-vascue/test-expo-ts), if you cannot make it to work, you can cross check the repo source.

Comment: Thank you Mic!  This helps.  I think my primary problem now is with the SafeAreaProvider.  I would like to run a series of tests by rendering the App.  However SafeAreaProvider is always empty.  What is the recommended way to handle this since it is mocked?  Should I move all of my logic to a separate component that would load inside the SafeAreaProvider and then render that instead of App?

Answer (score 0):

While Mic's reply answered the question, I still had a problem of not being able to test my app by rendering it in the test.  I figured out a few more steps to take on top of what Mic recommended.

1. Switch to using @testing-library/react-native (you will see why in the new test.)

> `yarn add @testing-library/react-native`

2. Modify App.tsx to include initialMetrics for the SafeAreaProvider.

> ```
> import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
> import React from 'react';
> import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
>
> import useCachedResources from './hooks/useCachedResources';
> import useColorScheme from './hooks/useColorScheme';
> import Navigation from './navigation';
>
> export default function App() {
>   const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
>   const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
>
>   if (!isLoadingComplete) {
>     return null;
>   } else {
>     return (
>       <SafeAreaProvider initialMetrics={{
>         frame: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 },
>         insets: { top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 },
>       }}>
>         <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
>         <StatusBar />
>       </SafeAreaProvider>
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

3. Rewrite App.test.tsx to use the testing library's render and waitFor:

> ```
> import React from 'react'; import { render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react-native';
>
> import App from './App';
>
> // mock the useCachedResources, so the if block in App.tsx can render component instead of returning null.
> jest.mock('./hooks/useCachedResources', () => jest.fn(() => true))
>
> describe('<App />', () => {   it('has 1 child', async () => {
>     let { getByText } = render(<App />);
>     await waitFor(() => getByText('Tab One'));       
>   });  
> });
> ```

4. Mock animated helper and reanimated.  (Solves an issue with a warning that will popup.

In package.json:

> ```
>   "jest": {
>     "preset": "jest-expo",
>     "moduleFileExtensions": [
>       "ts",
>       "tsx",
>       "js",
>       "jsx",
>       "json"
>     ],
>     "transformIgnorePatterns": [
>       "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
>     ],
>     "setupFiles": [
>       "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"
>     ]
>   },
> ```

In jest.setup.js

> ```
> import 'react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup';
>
> jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper');
>
> jest.mock('react-native-reanimated', () => {
>   const Reanimated = require('react-native-reanimated/mock');
>
>   // The mock for `call` immediately calls the callback which is incorrect
>   // So we override it with a no-op
>   Reanimated.default.call = () => {};
>
>   return Reanimated;
> });
> ```

If you make all of these changes you should get this test result:

> ```
>  PASS  components/__tests__/StyledText-test.js (10.84s)
>  PASS  ./app.test.tsx (24.138s)    
>
> Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
> Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
> Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
> Time:        24.982s
> Ran all test suites.
> ```